# how to fetch all branches and tags in visual studio git

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I opened Git Manage Branches in Visual Studio 2019. I need to fetch and pull other branches, not my checkout branch, if there are new incoming (as seen in Git changes when I checkout the branch). To do that, I will have to checkout that branch and fetch and pull. If there are many branches to fetch, I would do it one by one.

[image]

But how do I fetch all branches without me checking out that branch.

In SourceTree, which I am switching from, I just click the button Fetch and it will fetch all branches and I will be able to see from the left side bar which branches needs to be pulled.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open VS code
2. Source control icon on left banner(3rd icon from top)
3. Click on 3 dots on top beside refresh button
4. Click on Fetch.

[image]

Comment: This question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score -2):

```
Clone the source repository
Setup  branches to track their remote counterpart: git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
Fetch everything: git fetch --all
```

[visual studio git fetching image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibPTC.png)

Comment: OP is trying to do this from Visual Studio, not on the command line.